# How can I restore my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, restore

I changed the name of the Android Studio project folder in the Windows Explorer before I started Android Studio. Bad idea.

Now I get the error:

> Gradle sync failed: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mipsel-linux-android

And all my Activity files are replaced with one MainActivty that doesn't contains the things I've made.

Unfortunately I can't get a previous version with "show history" in Android Studio and i can,t get an older version via windows explorer "restore previous version"

I also tried to decompile it from the .apk on my phone. I got the layout and xml files but can't find my java classes.

I worked since weeks on this project and don't want to lose it.
Can anyone help me either fix the error or restore the .apk?
Thanks so much for all suggestions and ideas

Comment: the files are still present on the file system?

Comment: No the files are completely gone. And can't restore them. Now i tried to decompile the app form my phone but this didn't worked too. I will rewrite the whole App. Thanks for your quick responses and your help. I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

First close the broken project this can be done with `File` > `Close project`

Then you have to reopen the project from the new location ie. the renamed folder.

`File` > `Open...` browse in your filesystem for the project, select the folder and press `OK`

Wait for the gradle to sync and hopefully you won't have any problems!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when updating ndk-18. You updated the NDK to version 18 and it is missing the folders/files. You can download ndk-v17 manually and extract the search folder "toolchains" to copy the missing folders/files to your folder android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
From [github](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15#issuecomment-415423557).